# Plotting a discrete variable over time (scarf plot)

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plot

I have time series data from a repeated-measures eyetracking experiment.

The dataset consists of a number of respondents and for each respondent, there is 48 trials. 
The data set has a variable ('saccade') which is the transitions between eye-fixations and a variable ('time') which ranges for 0-1 for each trial. The transitions are classified into three different categories ('ver', 'hor' and 'diag').

Here is a script that will create a small [example data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wb37kuq2yiomsm4/example_data_for_scarf.csv) in python (one participant and two trials):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

saccade1 = np.array(['diag','hor','ver','hor','diag','ver','hor','diag','diag',
'diag','hor','ver','ver','ver','ver','diag','ver','ver','hor','hor','hor','diag',
'diag','ver','ver','ver','ver'])

time1 = np.array(range(len(saccade1)))/float(len(saccade1)-1)

trial1 = [1]*len(time1)

saccade2 = np.array(['diag','ver','hor','diag','diag','diag','hor','ver','hor',
'diag','hor','ver','ver','ver','ver','diag','ver','ver','hor','diag',
'diag','hor','hor','diag','diag','ver','ver','ver','ver','hor','diag','diag'])
time2 = np.array(range(len(saccade2)))/float(len(saccade2)-1)

trial2 = [2]*len(time2)

saccade = np.append(saccade1,saccade2)
time = np.append(time1,time2)
trial = np.append(trial1,trial2)
subject = [1]*len(time)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(subject)))
df['subject'] = subject
df['saccade'] = saccade
df['trial'] = trial
df['time'] = time
```

Alternatively I have made a csv-file with the same data which can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wb37kuq2yiomsm4/example_data_for_scarf.csv)

I would like to be able to make a so-called scarf plot to visualize the sequence of transitions over time, but I have no clue how to make these plots.

I would like plots (for each participant separately) where time is on the x-axis and trial is on the y-axis. For each trial I would like the transitions represented as colored "stacked" bars.

The only example I have of these kinds of plots are in the book "Eye Tracking - A comprehensive guide to methods and measures" (fig. 6.8b) [link](http://books.google.dk/books?id=5rIDPV1EoLUC&pg=SA6-PA9&lpg=SA6-PA9&dq=scarf+plot+eye+tracking&source=bl&ots=_u7CNYuNuK&sig=KPPK7Ag8hCw269ayjAhBL7tRWy4&hl=da&sa=X&ei=zXoXU-qYAYX8ywPl24HIDw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=scarf%20plot%20eye%20tracking&f=false)

Can anyone tell/help me in doing this?

(I can deal which python or R programming - preferably python)

Comment: Can you add some example data and an image of a similar plot?

Comment: @Thierry I have added some example data and a link to a source which use the plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution in R using ggplot2. You need to recode time2 so that it indicates the enlapsed time instead of the total time.

```
library(ggplot2)
dataset <- read.csv("~/Downloads/example_data_for_scarf.csv")
dataset$trial <- factor(dataset$trial)
dataset$saccade <- factor(dataset$saccade)
dataset$time2 <- c(0, diff(dataset$time))
dataset$time2[dataset$time == 0] <- 0
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = trial, y = time2, fill = saccade)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    coord_flip()
```

[image: scarf plot]